# adding extra cod files

Tags: blackberry

i want to know how do we add extra cod files to the existing cod file and update the jad, so that when my app installs on the Blackberry devce, it installs the extra cod files also. Actually the need is that i am using Ultralite which needs UltraLiteJ12.cod file to be installed, and i cannot make the users install UltraLiteJ12.cod  separately. Any idea how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:
There is an UpdateJad tool provided with every plugin component pack and JDE install.

This tool combines necessary jad files into 1 JAD file so you can deploy more than one COD.

There is an UpdateJad tool provided with every plugin component pack and JDE install.

This tool combines necessary jad files into 1 JAD file so you can deploy more than one COD.

For Eclipse:

YOUR_ECLIPSE_FOLDER/plugins/net.rim.ejde.componentpackPACK_VERSION/components/bin

For JDE:

YOUR_JDE_FOLDER/bin

Usage: updatejad.exe -q -n  [ ...
-q               Quiet mode
-n               No backup file
      File to be updated
 Other attributes to be added to input.jad

Source:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Install-two-cod-files-using-one-jad-file-OTA/m-p/491145

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite easy. Here's a PDF that describes [how to deploy multiple COD files in a single JAD file](http://assets.handango.com/marketing/developerTeam/BlackBerryOTADeployment.pdf). You should also read [Wireless Deployment over WAP](http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB17084).

Comment: Thanks Eric for the reply, Looks i have to edit this in notepad as per the above link, i found the utility to do this(see the post below).As this solution is also correct, i will mark this as an answer too.Thanks